# Validation - Using regex and trim in java Strings

Tags: java, regex, string

Less of a question and more of a validation I guess but I have created a Java application to list the available networks, through linux, and I just wanted to see if anyone knew of a better/ more efficient way to do it.

It runs fine on my machine, but I am aiming for it to run on less 'capable' machines, with limited power available too.

Essentially, I have an output from the terminal and I am handling the string in the following way. I am fairly new when it comes to regex so I was wondering if there ia better/more efficient way?

```
String t = s.replace("SSID:", "");
t = t.replace("\"", "");
t = t.trim();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"list the available networks"* What do you mean by "networks" ? Are you talking about available devices ?

Comment: Nope, I am calling a terminal command to list the available Wireless Networks.

Comment: Unless you're doing thousands of such operations per second in your program, optimizing it won't gain anything noticeable.

Comment: This sounds like premature micro-optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, this looks like a case of premature optimization.  I just want to address your (apparent) misconceptions about `replace()` and regexes.

The `replace()` method treats the search term as an exact string, not as a regex.  It's `replaceAll()` that does regex matching; with it, you can combine the two `replace()` operations into one, like this:

```
String t = s.replaceAll("\"|SSID:", "").trim();
```

You can even eliminate the `trim()` call and do *everything* with `replaceAll()`:

```
String t = s.replaceAll("\"|SSID:|^\\s+|\\s+$", "");
```

But just because it's all done in one operation doesn't necessarily mean it's more efficient--it could even be *less* efficient.  But in this case, any difference in efficiency will be so tiny you'll never even notice it.  You might as well stick with what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're processing the output of an external application, there's always the risk that one day that output will change.

So while performance doesn't matter much (the network listing program is likely to take several thousand times longer, not to mention the underlying cost of forking a new process), a more flexible solution would certainly be better.

As an example: you can use a single `String.replaceAll()` with a mixture of capturing and non-capturing groups to remove everything from the input except the bit that you need. This allows you to store the pattern in a config file, so you don't need to rewrite the replacement algorithm every time the output format changes. Even better, you can have several patterns in a config file, one for each known variant, and you can test which one matches your input.