# Validating a string against a predefined pattern in Java

Tags: java, string

I need to validate a String. Now I am validating it by looping and checking each character in the string.Is there any way to validate this using Pattern, Matcher.

String is comprised with `+`, `-` (hypen) and `0-9`

- '+' can only be appear in first character
- there can't be any two consecutive hypen(-)
- if '+' is in first character, second char can't be hypen
- if the string contains total of 10 to 13 digits then it is valid
- otherwise invalid

Comment: use regex... it should solve the problem...

Comment: Yes, it can be done with regex (though the length restriction is better left for a separate check).  Show us what you have tried and what's not working about it.

Comment: Always search the question on stackoverflow itself.... this is what I got here.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717874/validate-name-and-surname-using-regex, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473194/validation-using-regex-and-trim-in-java-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
string.matches("^(?=([\\D]?\\d){10,13}$)(?!.*--)(?!\\+-)\\+?[-0-9]*")
```

Explanation:

- `(?=([\\D]?\\d){10,13}$)` = lookahead for 10-13 instances of a digit with optional leading char (caters for one hyphen between digits or a leading plus), and that's all (`$` anchor prevents there being *more* than 13 allowed)
- `(?!.*--)` = negative lookahead for two hyphens
- `(?!\\+-)` = negative lookahead for plus then hyphen
- `\\+?[-0-9]*` = optional leading plus followed by only hyphens or digits

Here's some testing code (should produce no output):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "^(?=([\\D]?\\d){10,13}$)(?!.*--)(?!\\+-)\\+?[-0-9]*";

    String[] passes = { "+12345-12446-123", "123456-1-789", "123456789-0-1-2-3" };
    for (String string : passes)
        if (!string.matches(regex))
            System.out.println("should pass: " + string);

    String[] fails = { "123+435-1244", "123456--789", "+-123123123", "123", "11111-1-1-1-1-1-1111111111"};
    for (String string : fails)
        if (string.matches(regex))
            System.out.println("should fail: " + string);
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice regex and lovin' the test code

Comment: regex doesn't have any way to count digits that are not consecutive.  You will have to do that validation separately, like `int digits=<string>.replaceAll("+","").replaceAll("-","").length();` `if(digits<10 || digits>13){ <invalid> };`

Comment: Ahhh - I thought you meant total length 10-13. See edited answer for corrected regex

Comment: @prajeeshkumar Actually you are wrong there. See edited answer that *does* count non-consecutive digits.

Comment: I thought so that you can prove me wrong just after giving the comment, +1 :)

Comment: @Bohemian:Its still giving valid if total number of digits>13.

Comment: @android Please post the string that is failing the test

Comment: 11111-1-1-1-1-1-1111111111.There you see digits are mote than 13.But its giving me valid.It should be invalid.May be I couldn't make you understand

Comment: @android OK fixed it - it was missing an end of input anchor on the first lookahead. See edited answer, which now has your test too.

Comment: @Bohemian, still getting valid for digits>13

Comment: @android No - it does not: `System.out.println("11111-1-1-1-1-1-1111111111".matches("^(?=(.?\\d){10,13}$)(?!.*--)(?!\\+-)\\+?[-0-9]*"));` prints `false`. Did you look closely at the edited answer for the added `$`? I suggest you copy-paste my code verbatim.

Comment: 11111111111111.Here digits are 14.It should be invalid.But i am getting valid.Sorry that i am taking your time

Comment: @Bohemian: if digits>13 it should be invalid

Comment: OK! I have found the problem :) I changed the optional leading char before digits to `[^\\d]` meaning *not* a digit. Again, see edited answer :)

Comment: Now it works.Thanks a lot.I am feeling sorry that I can upvote you only once.Would you mind explaining a bit more why your expression works

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7302/discussion-between-bohemian-and-android)

Comment: +1 Love the regex and the detailed explanation (plus chat!)

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Pattern matching, via those classes directly or via String.matches()

Comment: whatever you are saying, better provide with example...

Answer (score 0):

You can even do this as follows

```
if(string.length()>=10 && string.length()<=13){
    if(string.charAt(0)=='+' && string.charAt(1)!='-'){
        if(!string.contains("--"){
            //valid
        }else{
            //invalid
        }
    }else{
          //invalid
}else{
     //invalid  
}
```